# How to tell `import` to always read files from the `src/` directory for a reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, npm

I inherited a react project that was working on my last computer.  But now it can't build on my new computer.  Specifically, I forgot how to get the `npm start` command to know where the project directory is.

For example, let's say I have the following two files:

```
// src/template/Page.js
import LoginComponent from 'component/Login.js'

// src/component/Login.js
export default function Gallery() { return <div></div>;}
```

Then when I run `npm start`, I get the error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'component/Login.js' in 'src/template/Page.js'
```

I vaguely remember that on my last computer, I used some hidden file, or possibly the `.env` file to tell `npm` to look for all react components under the `src/` directory, such that the term `src/` can be omitted from all the `import` statements in the code.

Does anyone know how to tell react or `npm` to always import components without always spelling out the `src/` prefix?

---

NOTE:
I also see a `.vscode` directory with these files:

```
// .vscode/settings.json
{
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": false
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}

// .vscode/launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
        }
    ]
}
```

I think these files might be related to my solution last time I got this working

---

In my `package.json`, I see these lines:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
...
```

---

Also, my `package.json` says I'm using `"react": "^16.6.1"` and my `npm -v` shows `5.5.1`. I don't remember what `npm` version I was using on my last computer.  So not sure if that would matter.

Comment: What is your `start` script in package.json? `compilerOptions` doesn't belong in VS Code's settings, but it looks like something that is supposed to be in tsconfig.json when using TypeScript. Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: @StephenJennings i'm not using typescript. I just added to my question saying i see `"start": "react-scripts start"`.   I remember vaguely I just needed to put one more declaration somewhere and everying worked....just can't remember because it's been so many years

Comment: `react-scripts` means you're using Create React App, which is important information for this question. Create React App should take care of this for you, you shouldn't need to add any configuration anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [*jsconfig.json* to configure absolute imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports) (if you were using TypeScript, you would instead use *tsconfig.json*). This file is vital to your project working correctly, so you should commit this to source control so you don't have to remake it on each machine:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I did not know Create React App supported this, I learned something today from your question. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried and this `jsconfig.json` had no effect.  I do see the `{"compilerOptions":{"baseUrl":"src"}}` in my `.vscode/settings.json`.  Is there a way to tell `npm start` to use the `.vscode/settings.json` file?  I also updated my question to say that my current `npm -v` shows `5.5.1`, and react ` 16.6.11` so not sure if that would make a difference in all this.

Comment: thank you for assistance . I ended up adding `NODE_PATH=src` to my `.env` file and that fixed everything.  I posted it as answer here so that i never forget

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it work. I added this line to my `.env` file:

```
NODE_PATH=src
```

And then everything worked.  Taken from documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

> If the NODE_PATH environment variable is set to a colon-delimited list
> of absolute paths, then Node.js will search those paths for modules if
> they are not found elsewhere.
>
> On Windows, NODE_PATH is delimited by semicolons (;) instead of
> colons.
>
> NODE_PATH was originally created to support loading modules from
> varying paths before the current module resolution algorithm was
> defined.
>
> NODE_PATH is still supported, but is less necessary now that the
> Node.js ecosystem has settled on a convention for locating dependent
> modules. Sometimes deployments that rely on NODE_PATH show surprising
> behavior when people are unaware that NODE_PATH must be set. Sometimes
> a module's dependencies change, causing a different version (or even a
> different module) to be loaded as the NODE_PATH is searched.
>
> Additionally, Node.js will search in the following list of
> GLOBAL_FOLDERS:
>
> ```
> 1: $HOME/.node_modules
> 2: $HOME/.node_libraries
> 3: $PREFIX/lib/node
> ```
>
> Where $HOME is the user's home directory, and $PREFIX is the Node.js
> configured node_prefix.
>
> These are mostly for historic reasons.
>
> It is strongly encouraged to place dependencies in the local
> node_modules folder. These will be loaded faster, and more reliably.